# Time based build scheduling in Teamcity

Tags: teamcity

In Teamcity (version 7.1) how do I set up a build to be triggered to run every 20 mins for example?

I notice you can set up timed based schedules, for example "Run this build at 18:00 everyday" but that's not quite what I want.

Comment: Kind of off topic, but I just want to point out that apparently the Quartz tool used by TC for cron support doesn't use the normal Unix standard for day of the week, which is typically 0-7. (You can see in the screenshots below that the day of the week ranges from 1-7 instead.) This means that if you want M-F, you would need to use 2-6 instead of the standard 1-5. Or, you can also use "MON-FRI".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a Schedule trigger with cron expressions to do this.

I believe you'd need this one:

- Seconds: 0
- Minutes: **0,20,40**
- Hours: *
- Day of month: *
- Month: *
- Day of week: ?
- Year: *

(or whatever interval you desire)

TeamCity uses Quartz for scheduling, see more [cron expression examples](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger).

Comment: It should be noted this won't work for something like 'run every 75 minutes'.  CronTrigger only allows scheduling within each time element bucket (i.e. Hours, days, minutes).  This is not the same thing as Run every X time period.

Answer (score 1):

The cron expression you need is "0 0/20 * * * ? *"

Answer (score 1):

See [these cron expression examples](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Configuring+Schedule+Triggers#ConfiguringScheduleTriggers-Examples)

The the cron expression here:

Under the Build Configuration Settings

Triggers > "Add new trigger" > "Schedule Trigger"

Select "advanced (cron expression) from the "When:" dropdown

This is for TeamCity version: 2017.1.2

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

run every half hour
Hours set "*" - run every hour
Minutes set "0,30" - run every 0 minute and 30 minute

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

Use this corn expression, `0 0/20 0/1 * * ? *`, and check the trigger rule and branch filter.

Answer (score -1):

You can trigger builds using HTTP and so you could do what you are asking for by making such requests using your operating systems task scheduler.

http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Accessing+Server+by+HTTP

Comment: That sounds overly complicated for this use case. You'd have to write a separate program to periodically tell TeamCity to fire off a job, instead of telling TeamCity to do it itself.

Comment: I think a down-vote is a bit harsh. Yours might be a simpler solution but what I have suggested would work and is arguably more flexible.

Comment: Thanks to you both.  I had considered programmatically doing it, but the cron suggestion above is the easiest to manage.  Thanks.

Comment: I disagree. The OP asked how to do this with TeamCity. Your solution requires writing a separate program, which to my mind is working around TeamCity instead of using it. Thus, to me, this didn't answer the question.

Comment: I don't think id expect to look in a task scheduler to find the reason a build was being triggered. Thats definitly obscure especially as the tool provides a method.

Comment: Down voted, because this is a really bad idea.  TeamCity is an infrastructure product, and should be treated as such.  Doing this kind of spaghetti configuration and management is creating a nightmare for the person who follows after you.